# Set specific cell of multi-indexed Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (df_test) with row labels ('letters') and column names ('numbers') which can be grouped by row labels.

```
>>> letters = ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
>>> n = {'numbers': [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,2,3]}

>>> df_test = pd.DataFrame(n, index=letters)
>>> print df_test

       numbers        
a      0
a      1
a      2
a      3
a      4
b      0
b      1
b      2
c      0
c      1
c      2
c      3
```

I want to create a new column called 'Position'. The first row of each group (i.e. group a, group b, group c) should be 'S', the last row should be 'E', and the intervening rows should be 'M'. *(For start, middle and end. ;))* It would look like this:

```
       numbers    Position
a      0          S
a      1          M
a      2          M
a      3          M
a      4          E
b      0          S
b      1          M
b      2          E
c      0          S
c      1          M
c      2          M
c      3          E
```

I have tried using a combination of .loc and .iloc to assign my new value to the correct cell but get an error message.

```
>>> df_test['Position'] = 'M'
>>> for idxName,frame in df_test.groupby(level=0):
        df_test.loc[idxName,('Position')].iloc[0] = 'S'
        df_test.loc[idxName,('Position')].iloc[-1] = 'E'

__main__:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
__main__:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I imagine that the problem arises from trying to use .iloc[ ] after having used .loc[ ] but I don't know Pandas well enough to have a different solution and haven't found anything online despite hours of searching. Any help with (a) understanding why I am getting the warning and (b) setting my cells to the correct values would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because @piRSquared's answer didn't work with my DataFrame for reasons still unknown, this is what I ended up going with.

```
>>> letters = ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
>>> n = {'numbers': [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,2,3]}
>>> df_test = pd.DataFrame(n, index=letters)
>>> df_test['Position'] = 'M'

>>> df_test2 = pd.DataFrame()

>>> for idxName,frame in df_test.groupby(level=0):
        frameLen = len(df_test.ix[idxName])
        df_s = df_test.ix[idxName].iloc[0:1].copy()
        df_e = df_test.ix[idxName].iloc[-1:frameLen].copy()
        df_s['Position'] = 'S'
        df_e['Position'] = 'E'
        df_test2 = df_test2.append([df_s,df_test.loc[idxName].ix[1:-1],df_e],ignore_index=False)

>>> df_test2
     numbers Position
a    0        S
a    1        M
a    2        M
a    3        M
a    4        E
b    0        S
b    1        M
b    2        E
c    0        S
c    1        M
c    2        M
c    3        E
```

I will try to figure out how to do this using 'apply' if possible, but for now this hack works.

Answer (score 0):

write a function to `apply` with in a `groupby`

```
def first_last_me(df, c='Position'):
    df[c] = 'M'
    df.iloc[0, -1] = 'S'
    df.iloc[-1, -1] = 'E'
    return df

df_test.groupby(level=0).apply(first_last_me)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this works perfectly on my mock-up DataFrame. Unfortunately, when I tried applying it to my actual DataFrame (which is basically the same structure but has many more columns), I got the following error message: `"cannot reindex from a duplicate axis."`Do you know why this might be happening? (df_test has an index with 12 entries from a to c and 2 columns; my other df has an index with 25 entries from B01_H01 to B03_H03 and 31 columns.)

Comment: I would also have thought that getting rid of the `concat` line would make a difference but I'm still getting the same error. There must be something wrong with my DataFrame. I'll play around with it and post a new question if possible. Thanks for all your help!